# Database operation using transaction methods in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am reading `SQLite` in Android, I see that there is transaction methods to do CRUD operation on `SQLite` in Android, same thing can be done without transactions methods.

Transaction methods : `beginTransaction`, `setTransactionSuccessfull`, `endTransaction`.

In what cases should we use the transactions method over simple approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sqlite writes are in transactions. If you don't start one explicitly yourself, one will be started and committed for you implicitly. This implicit transaction finishes automatically when the statement finishes. [Further reading](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Generally, you want explicit transactions when you want to group more than one database operation as one to maintain [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties of your data model. As a consequence, you also gain performance benefit since you don't need to wait for I/O after each statement, only at commit.

It's also worth noting that sqlite does not support nested transactions but the Android sqlite API emulates them using nest level counting. As a consequence, any nested Android sqlite transaction really commits or rollbacks when the outermost transactions is committed or rolled back.

Comment: Nice explanation, I have one doubt how this can increase performance of it ?